# What is the goal of self.self == self check in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

backbone.js starts with:

```
//Establish the root object, `window` (`self`) in the browser, or `global` on the server.  
//We use `self` instead of `window` for `WebWorker` support.  
var root = (typeof self == 'object' && self.self == self && self) ||  
           (typeof global == 'object' && global.global == global && global);
```

What is `self.self == self` for? When can it be false?
Same about `global.global == global`.

Comment: I think they should check `self` first and then check `self.self`. Otherwise, if `self` was `null`, `self.self` would throw.

Comment: The `self` chicanery probably has something to do with [`window.self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self), not sure about `global`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this article answers the question.

[The Global Object in Various JS Environments](https://zzz.buzz/2016/06/30/the-global-object-in-various-javascript-environments/)

In short:

- `typeof self === 'object' && self.self === self && self` detects the global object in browser environments with support for code run in WebWorker at the same time.
- `typeof global === 'object' && global.global === global && global` detects the global object on the server (e.g. Node.js).
- Using `this` as a fallback to add support for code run in Node.js vm module.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Mistake(x);
    self = this;
    x.on("event", function() {
        console.log(self);
    });
}
new Mistake(…);
```

Did you spot it? Now we've got a global `self` that is not the [`self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) that backbone expects. So it checks whether `self` actually is the global object, which is likely to be the case when `self` is an object and the object has the "global variable" `self` as a property that points to the object itself.

Same for `global`.

Answer (score 0):

I think [here](https://github.com/caolan/async/pull/804) you can find at least part of the explanation.